# JavaScript - change a set of links that contain specific text and variable ID element

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, setattribute, getattribute

I am really new to JavaScript, but here's what I am starting with:

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  var anc = anchors[i];
  if (anc.getAttribute("href") == "/catalog?id=123456789") { 
    anc.setAttribute("href", "/catalog?id=123456789#specificID");
    anc.setAttribute("target", "iframe");
} }
```

I have a web page with a list of links that are similar to `/catalog?id=123456789` where the ID can be any combination of 9 numbers. I want to target all of the links (including the ID), append a page anchor at the end of the link, and then switch them with the existing links on the page. I would be willing to try using JQuery, but the site I am working on uses a MooTools library so it may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substr()` to get the beginning of the URL and just match that:

```
var href = anc.getAttribute("href")
if (href.substr(0, 12) == "/catalog?id=") {
    anc.setAttribute("href", href + "#specificID");
    anc.setAttribute("target", "iframe");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution building on barmar's solution using functional JavaScript and the MooTools Array.prototype.each function:

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');
anchors.filter(function(anc) {
    anc.getAttribute('href').substr(0,12) === '/catalog?id=';
}).each(function(anc) {
    anc.setAttribute('href', href + '#specificID');
    anc.setAttribute('target', 'iframe');
});
```

There's no need to go add JQuery to get this done; Mootools appears to have all the plumbing required.

Be sure to use the === operator when comparing for equality or you may not get the results you expect.

Comment: I want each URL to be similar to `/catalog?id=123456789#specificID`. Either it's not working on my site or I'm not getting the correct value for `substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var anchors = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anc = anchors[i];
    if (anc.getAttribute("href").indexOf("/catalog?id=") != -1) { // If the anchor's 'href' attribute contains '/catalog?id='
      anc.setAttribute("href", anc.getAttribute("href") + "#specificID");
      anc.setAttribute("target", "iframe");
    } 
}
```

In Javascript, `foo.indexOf(bar)` returns -1 if the string `foo` does not contain the string `bar`.